# Any benefit in sockets from multiple cores? (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, kernel

Cant find myself the answer for such a question:

Is there any benefit/boost to sockets in general at multi-core machine. I mean is there maybe some kind of sharing access to packets queue incoming to kernel from the ethernet-card driver or smth.

I understand that when it comes up to API call there can be multiple threads working with one socket instance, but it is up to programmer to synchronize and play correctly with calls to read/write/close/select etc. So at that level i see benefit only in working with dispatched packets and post processing etc... Or there is no speed boost until the packet copied during system call and transferred to user space?

Comment: Checksum offloading comes to mind...

Comment: ...if the checksums aren't already done in hardware.

Comment: I think that you could benefit only when working with very fast connections working at full throttle, with modern hardware and "normal" networks the common case is the network itself being the bottleneck.

Comment: I think that the implementation of the kernel-level functions regarding sockets takes all the blame, multicore machines can help in multi-threading, but how the kernel handles the incoming packets that's the case.

Comment: There's a huge boost at the kernel level.  Many Ethernet and wireless cards have hardware multi-queue support, which works in Linux.  The Receive Packet Steering feature contributed by Google works together with multi-queue by queuing incoming packets on the core that they will be processed on, increasing cache locality.  More info: http://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/NetScalingGuide and http://lwn.net/Articles/362339/

Comment: oh...wow. it will take some time for me to read and process those links.stating :)

Comment: pipes (thru `pipe(2)` or `socketpair`), named pipes (see `mkfifo` function) or `AF_UNIX` sockets are supposed to be faster than TCP/IP sockets to `localhost`

Comment: **@g.inozemtsev**, if you post ur comment as answer ill mark it as usefull if you dont mined. a VERY interesting slice of information found in google groups and tests etc etc...all coming from your links:) Thats the answer i think. With google patch from 2.6.35 it really can boost performance

Comment: with an RT Kernel I can see that interrupt handling is spread on the cores.. so on the core(s) where your app runs there is more processing power left.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of multi-core depends on how concurrency can be achieved in your algorithm. Take ethernet receiving as example, there are 4 tasks involved in it.

1. On receiving packet, the NIC hardware trigger an interrupt and CPU handle interrupt in interrupt context.
2. The network stack handle RX packet in software irq mechanism. The software irq requests can be run concurrently on multiple CPU. In network stack RX function, it pass network buffer to socket and wakes up user thread pendning at the socket.
3. The user thread waked up and continue user application code to receive or processes received network packets.

1) can only run at one CPU, 2) can run in multiple CPU and 3) can also runs on multiple CPU for multi-process or multi-thread applications.

Comment: For 1) that is not strictly true, when using RSS (Receive Side Scaling) for example of NICs with multiple receive queues incoming packets can filter into different RX queues and the interrupt for each queue can be dispatched to a separate CPU core.

Answer (score 2):

Following from @Greg Inozemtsev's comment. NICs with multiple receive queues can filter incoming traffic into different queues. Each queue can generate a unique interrupt to the CPU to signal incoming packets. Each queue can be assigned a different interrupt that can be dispatched to a unique CPU core.

[Linux supports various techniques](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt) in the Kernel such as:

- RSS: Receive Side Scaling
- RPS: Receive Packet Steering
- RFS: Receive Flow Steering
- Accelerated Receive Flow Steering
- XPS: Transmit Packet Steering

Lets say all the packets are destined to your machine IP on port 80 and you have used `socket()` and `listen()` to create a socket on port 80. Traffic is coming into your NIC from a variety of source IPs so its being hashed into multiple receive queues (meaning the hardware interrupts are being spread across multiple CPU cores thanks to RSS). You can use the native kernel socket option PACKET_FANOUT to spread the load across multiple worker threads within your application.

If you look to 3rd party libraries [NetMap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/), [DPDK](http://dpdk.org/) and [VPP](https://fd.io/), just as examples, these can all be used to scale up even further by take you down to zero copy RX/TX with the caveat you need to write some of the network protocol code your self depending on which 3rd party library you use.

There are many many things to consider here, far too much to cover in one SO question. In answer to your original question; yes. Although I have tried to provide a bit of extra information.

For reading on RSS/RPS/RFS etc:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/

For further reading related to native PACKET_FANOUT and PACKET_MMAP:

http://kukuruku.co/hub/nix/capturing-packets-in-linux-at-a-speed-of-millions-of-packets-per-second-without-using-third-party-libraries

http://yusufonlinux.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/data-link-access-and-zero-copy.html?m=1

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt

Further reading related to NetMap as an example of 3rd party library

https://blog.cloudflare.com/single-rx-queue-kernel-bypass-with-netmap/

Further reading on NUMA and affinity:

https://null.53bits.co.uk/index.php?page=numa-and-queue-affinity

https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-achieve-low-latency/